# Как отсортировать по типу файла?

Tags: c++, c, сортировка, структуры, пузырьковая-сортировка

Мне нужно отсортировать таблицу дескрипторов файлов методом обмена по ключу - тип файла. Таблица дескрипторов представлена массивом структур. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
struct file {
    char name[8]; //Имя файла
    char tip[3];  //Тип файла
    struct data {  //Дата создания файла
        int dd;
        int mm;
        int yy;
    } d;
    int col; //Количество обращений
    int size; //Размер файла
    struct time {  //Время последней модификации
        int hh;
        int mm;
    } t;
};
void bubbleSort(struct file f[], int n) {
    int i,j;
    char 
    for (i =0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = n; j>=i; j--) {

        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для начала лучше вы подскажите что вам нужно отсортировать?

Comment: чтобы сортировать по какому то типу, нужно определить  оператор больше для этого типа.  Тут неясно, по какому параметру вы хотите сравнивать файлы: по имени, по типу, по размеру или по времени последней модификации? Вы сначала решите этот вопрос

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Мне нужно отсортировать таблицу дескрипторов файлов , которая представлена в виде структуры по ключу типа файла

Comment: @ARHovsepyan по типу

Comment: Меня терзают смутные сомнения насчет того, что вы этот самый "тип" поместите в 3 символа, как и имя в 8... неужели вы под DOS'ом работаете? да и тогда - места под завершающий ноль не остается, и советы сравнивать с помощью strcmp не будут работать.

Answer (score 0):

Если `n` - это количество элементов в массиве структур

```
void bubbleSort(struct file f[], int n) {
    file temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; ++j) {
           if (f[j] > f[j + 1]) {
               temp = f[j];
               f[j] = f[j + 1];
               f[j + 1] = temp;
           }

        }
    }
}
```

Это функция сортировки, но, как видите, она не будет работать без определения оператора сравнения для структуры `file`.

```
bool operator>(file &second)
{
    return (strcmp(tip, second.tip) > 0);
}
```

Не проверял, но должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool operator >(const file& f1, const file& f2)
{
    return strcmp(f1.tip, f2.tip) > 0;
}

void bubbleSort(file f[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = (n - 1); j > i; j--)
        {
            if (f[j - 1] > f[j])
            {
                file t = f[j - 1];
                f[j - 1] = f[j];
                f[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Учитывая, что tip[3], а обычно в именах DOS/Windows как раз 3 символа, там не будет завершающего NUL. Поэтому все strcmp надо скорее всего заменить на `strncmp(f1.tip, f2.tip, 3)`. А вообще за такое отсутствие NUL выругать и потребовать добавить.